# how does forEach works in this case?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have 2 buttons which they activate/deactivate divs, button next activate next div and button prev deactivate current div.
function update gets called in each click, im trying to understand how comparing the index of the array and currentActive is helping us in this case.
I comment out the rest of the code to follow the value of idx but I get confused with the output....................

```js
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
const next = document.getElementById('next');
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
let currentActive = 1;

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentActive++;
  if (currentActive > circles.length) {
    currentActive = circles.length;
  }
  update();
});

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentActive--;
  if (currentActive < 1) {
    currentActive = 1;
  }

  update();
});

function update() {
  console.log(' - - - - - - - - ')    
  console.log('update function, currentActive = '+ currentActive )
  
  circles.forEach((circle, idx) => {

    console.log('idx->'+ idx + ', ==Active?->' + (idx===currentActive) + ', div->' + circle.textContent )

    
   // if (idx < currentActive) {
   //   console.log('index is:' + idx, 'current is :' + currentActive);

    // circle.classList.add('active');
     // }
    /* else {
            circle.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });

    if (currentActive === 1) {
        prev.disabled = false;
    } else if (currentActive === circles.length) {
        next.disabled = true;
        prev.disabled = false;
    } else {
        prev.disabled = false;
        next.disabled = false;
    } */

  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { 
  top        : 0;
  left       : 30%  !important;
  max-height : 100% !important;
  width      : 70%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <title>Progress Steps</title>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
      <div class="circle active">1</div>
      <div class="circle">2</div>
      <div class="circle">3</div>
      <div class="circle">4</div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" id="prev" disabled>Prev</button>
    <button class="btn" id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it iterates through all elements having class that includes `circle`

Comment: if you mean class circle, the output of console log should be 4 elements of array, why its 2 only? and what is the value of idx in the beginning?

Comment: you have a condition ... so, no, it's not 2 only ... it's 2, then 3, then 4 as you click next - your condition means that the console.log won't be run for ever iteration, but every iteration is being run

Comment: @Bravo having for loop background got me confused. Correct me if im wrong: forEach doesnt have a counter, it goes through the array and show the out based on the applied condition. right?

Comment: It's like you say in English. For each circle in circles do this (the function's body). You cannot use `for` loop here because `circles` is not an actual array, but rather a NodeList. You can however transform it to an array by using `Array.from(circles)`.

Comment: @BlackMath right and in (circle,idx), circle is implying to each item of that Node list, right? cause iI changed the name for sake of test to A as (A,idx) and result was the same.

Comment: forEach doesn't *show* anything ... your callback code does ... conditionally

Comment: @bigly Right, the names inside `forEach` are up to the developer, as long as they understand that the first argument refers to the item itself, while the second to its index in the list.

Comment: inside `forEach` successives value of idx are 0,1,2,3. -> **it start at ZERO** and finnish at Three. There is no value at 4, which is only the size (==length).

Comment: your HTML is invalid, because your ` <div class="container">` should be inside the `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

I think what bothers you is that in computing, the first index of a list is zero.

here is your code (revisited)

```js
const progress     = document.getElementById('progress')
    , bt_prev      = document.getElementById('prev')
    , bt_next      = document.getElementById('next')
    , divs_circle  = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')
    , Last_circle  = divs_circle.length -1
    , progressText =
       [ 'payment first step'
       , 'payment second step'
       , 'payment third step'
       , 'payment last step'
       , 'payment done !'
       ]
    ;
var currentActive = 0  // the first index is zero 
  ;
function setActivCircle()
  {
  divs_circle.forEach((circle, idx )=>
    {
    if ( idx === currentActive ) circle.classList.add('active')
    else                         circle.classList.remove('active')

    if( idx < currentActive ) circle.classList.add('done')
    else                      circle.classList.remove('done')
    })
  progress.textContent = progressText[currentActive] 
  bt_prev.disabled     = (currentActive === 0) || (currentActive > Last_circle)
  bt_next.disabled     = (currentActive > Last_circle)
  bt_next.textContent  = (currentActive === Last_circle) ? 'Terminate' : 'Next'
  
  console.clear()
  console.log(`currentActive value is ${currentActive}, last Idx value is ${Last_circle}`)
  }
setActivCircle() // first attempt

bt_next.onclick = () =>
  {
  ++currentActive 
  setActivCircle()
  }
bt_prev.onclick = () =>
  {
  --currentActive
  setActivCircle()
  }
```

```css
div.circle {
  padding : .2em;
  width   : 5em;
  border  : 1px solid grey;
  margin  : .2em;
  }
div.active {
  background-color : lightblue;
  }
div.done {
  background-color : lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
    <div class="circle" >1</div>
    <div class="circle" >2</div>
    <div class="circle" >3</div>
    <div class="circle" >4</div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" id="prev" > Prev</button>
  <button class="btn" id="next" > Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code work for this purpose but the code I mentioned, keeps the previous numbers active going forward.  consider it as online payment process..Step on active, then step 2 is active..and so on

Comment: prev button doesnt work properly, I have the proper code though, was just trying to understand it.

Comment: your code still has problem, buttons deactivate at the end. code itself is not an issue for me, forEach and conditions inside were my main confusion.

Comment: @bigly You told me to understand this as the steps of a payment, so it seems more logical to me to deactivate everything once the payment has been made. I changed the text to show that

Comment: @bigly Seems to me you still didn't understand how the `forEach` works. I have Added a console.log to show the 2  indexes values, hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

“….im trying to understand how comparing the index of the array and currentActive is helping us in this case.”

Think your first idx is 0, and onload your `currentActive=1` then your condition is saying if `idx<currentActive` , it will receive a class `active`.

Now see what happens when you click the next,
As your `currentActive` is 1 onload, when you click `next` then happens `currentActive++` that makes 2, now see your condition, if `idx<currentActive` (this time idx is 1) and the condition is true, so it will receive a class `active`, but the prev will remove the class `active` (and on each click it resets the values as per your condition) …. Now see your other codes and try to understand also the prev click and other codes.